# how to put a boolean method from another class in an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, boolean

Sorry if this question is too bare bones, but simply put, what is the correct way to do this:

```
OtherClass ClassObj = new OtherClass();

if(ClassObj.booleanMethod().equals(true)){
    do a thing
}
```

I know this is a basic logical error and misconception, I just haven't been able to find the answer so far.

Comment: if(Class.booleanMethod()){//if ture }else{//if the value is false}

Comment: object declaration should starts with small letter and it should not be named like 'Class'

Comment: yes UUIIUI i know i did it just to show what i was trying to do in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
if(classObj.booleanMethod()){
    do a thing if its true
}else{
    do a thing if its false
}
```

Comment: so how do i get the if to check if its true or false?